# Default Value for the GREP_COLORS Environment Variable

Tags: linux, grep, environment-variables

On my Ubuntu 20 system, the default coloring when the `grep` `--colors=auto` option is used is red text on the normal background. This behavior can be overridden by providing a value to the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable. For example, `export GREP_COLORS='1;37;41'` causes `grep` to display matches in the normal text color on a red background, and thereafter, `echo $GREP_COLORS` displays the value just set. However, `echo $GREP_COLORS` is a blank line before the export. Why is this the case? In particular, why does `GREP_COLORS` appear not to have a default value?

Comment: Why should it have a value? Any value it has overrides `grep`'s builtin defaults, so if a distro is happy with those, why should it set that variable?

Comment: and also, environment variables are just values that get inherited down from one process to its children, they're not any sort of global things that would just exist. The fact that `grep` uses the variable isn't enough to make it appear in other processes. (Or even in `grep` itself, unless it sets it explicitly, but it doesn't really need to.)

Answer (score 4):

> why does GREP_COLORS appear not to have a default value?

Because the environment variable `GREP_COLORS` *can be used* to override the existing default colors. It doesn't mean that it *must* be used.

The [GNU grep](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/) **default** colors are defined into `grep.c`:

```
/* The color strings used for matched text.
   The user can overwrite them using the deprecated
   environment variable GREP_COLOR or the new GREP_COLORS.  */
static const char *selected_match_color = "01;31";      /* bold red */
static const char *context_match_color  = "01;31";      /* bold red */

/* Other colors.  Defaults look damn good.  */
static const char *filename_color = "35";       /* magenta */
static const char *line_num_color = "32";       /* green */
static const char *byte_num_color = "32";       /* green */
static const char *sep_color      = "36";       /* cyan */
static const char *selected_line_color = "";    /* default color pair */
static const char *context_line_color  = "";    /* default color pair */
```

and later there is a function `parse_grep_colors (void)` trying to get a value from `GREP_COLORS` environment variable. If it's empty or if its syntax is not valid, it will be ignored. For example if you set `GREP_COLORS='random text'`, it will be ignored.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks! Since `grep.c` doesn't appear to be on my system, I'm assuming I would need to recompile `grep` from source in order to change the default via this file. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need to recomplile `grep`, grep colors are totally configurable. If you want any `grep` command in any interactive shell of your user to use different colors, just add into your `./bashrc` file: `export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'` and `source` it. Change the numbers above to the new values you like. `man grep` and search for `GREP_COLORS` to see the syntax and how to set this variable.